bash perl run argument as command
I want to run a passed parameter as a command.
Without using a parameter, it works as I expect:
echo 'Hello world' | perl -0777snE 'print'

Output:
Hello world

Using a parameter instead, no output appears:
options='print'
echo 'Hello world' | perl -0777snE '$o' -- -o="$options"

How can I solve the problem?

For the sake of code streamlining, the code is large and I only posted the line I'm interested in and I need to execute a parameter as a command in perl and it's not convenient for me to enter the command directly because it varies based on conditions.

What question didn't I answer?

For the sake of code streamlining, the code is large and I only posted the line I'm interested in and I need to execute a parameter as a command in perl and it's not convenient for me to enter the command directly because it varies based on conditions.

What does -o do? I can't find that. Do you want something to the effect of perl -0777snE "$options"?

-o is simply a named parameter of my choosing.

$o is a variable, not a command.

@MarioPalumbo Ok, so perl -0777snE 'eval $o' -- -o="$options" then? Feels a bit dangerous though...

$o is a variable containing the print command.

@MarioPalumbo No, $o contains the text print, not a command. You have to let the perl interpreter interpret the content in order for it to be able to execute it.

eval is a very dangerous way to go. It's much safer to use a dispatch table or some other translation from strings to commands.

What is a dispatch table?

@MarioPalumbo He means something like %cmd = ( print => sub { print }) A set of commands with code to execute

Tip: -0777 can be replaced with -g since (IIRC) 5.36.

Tip: -E isn't future compatible. Upgrading Perl could break your code. It's safer to use -Mv5.xx and -e instead of -E. (Replace 5.xx with something the desired version.)

options contains Perl code to execute. Simply pass the code to -e.
perl -0777ne"$options"

If you want to pass the code to Perl by variable for some unseen reason, you will need to ask Perl to execute the string as Perl code. eval EXPR achieves this.
perl -s0777ne'eval $o; die $@ if $@;' -- -o="$options"

Either way, code is an input. This is a usually a very bad idea. There are security concerns, it's fragile, it requires advanced skills, it's hard to maintain backward compatibility through upgrades, etc.

If you want the perl interpreter to treat the text stored in $o as perl code, you can use eval:
perl -0777snE 'eval $o' -- -o="$options"
#              ^^^^

Note that eval often called evil eval because it opens up for malicious code to be injected into your script.

A safer option would be to have a set of pre-defined commands that the user of your script could select from. Here's an example where print and foo are pre-defined commands that the script understands:
#!/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %commands = (
    print => sub { print "@_" },
    foo   => sub { print "doing something else to @_" },
);

my $cmdstr = shift;
die "USAGE: $0 command\n" unless $cmdstr;

my $command = $commands{$cmdstr};
die "$0: ERROR: \"$cmdstr\" is an unknown command.\n" unless $command;

while (<STDIN>) {
    $command->($_);
}


Re: "Note that eval often called evil eval because it opens up for malicious code to be injected into your script": Not just malicious code; it makes everything more fragile and harder to debug.

@ruakh Yes, the list can be made long :-)
